# How To Make ToolStripControlHost Highlight When Moused Over

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstripcontrolhost

I've created a custom menuitem using ToolStripControlHost but I wan't it to be highlighted when moused over like normal items:

[image]

Notice how the item "None" is highlighed because the mouse cusor is over it. The last item is my custom control which isn't highlighted if I mouse over it. Its made of a label and a textbox.

I've tried directly calling OnMouseEnter() and OnMouseLeave() of the control host whenever the label is moused over but that doesn't work.

Anyone succedded in doing this? Or am I going to be forced to write all my own rendering code? I was hoping there was a simple way to do it.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: I think I did, but the code was at a former job so I don't have it to lookup what the solution was. Sorry.